# IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin plugin - "there aren't configurators available"

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm having problems using the Kotlin plugin in IntelliJ IDEA. First, upon opening a kotlin project, it pops up that I need to configure Kotlin in this project. But when I do so from the Tools menu, it says "there aren't configurators available"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized the problem was my Gradle plugin was disabled.

Comment: Gradle was enabled for me, but toggling it off and back on in plugins did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1. Cneal build, Synchronize, Invalidate Caches and Restart didn't help.

The only thing that worked was to make a change to a `build.gradle` file and click "Sync now".

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with one of my Kotlin gradle project.
Go to `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`. There should be a `Reimport all Gradle Projects` icon at the top. (Circle with double arrows). Just click on it and it should refresh your gradle project with Kotlin configuration.

Comment: This just worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me with Kotlin 1.3 and IntelliJ 2018.2.6.

I tried all the above solutions listed---none of them worked until I actually deleted the .idea folder and .iml file from my Kotlin gradle project directory and then re-imported them in IDEA, then all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Android Studio and then going to File -> Invalidate Caches, checking "Clear file system cache and Local History" and "Clear VCS Log caches and indexes", and clicking the "Invalidate and Restart" submit button fixed the problem for me :)